# Bayesian probability of negative COVID-19 test

Tags: probability, bayesian, covid-19

Suppose if the person is infected, the test will be positive with a probability of 70%. The probability that a healthy person gets a negative test is 99.5%. The prior probability of being infected is 0.1%.

What is the probability that someone is infected after they have gotten a negative test result, given the test parameters above?

My idea would be: $Pr(inf|neg)=\frac{Pr(neg|inf)Pr(inf)}{Pr(neg)}= \frac{0.3\times0.001}{0.3\times0.001+0.995\times0.999}=0.0003$

But can we write the same if it asks to express the posterior probability of being infected after a negative test result as a function of the test’s sensitivity (i.e. how reliable it is at avoiding false negatives) and as a function of the prior infection
probability.

So: $Pr(inf|neg)=\frac{Pr(neg|inf)Pr(inf)}{Pr(neg)}= \frac{Pr(neg|inf)}{Pr(neg)}Pr(inf)?$

Comment: That looks like the same thing $\frac{0.3}{0.3\times0.001+0.995\times0.999}\times0.001$. So yes you can

Comment: Yeah—this seems like a PEMDAS question. Whether you divide or multiply first will give you the same result.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the same thing $$\dfrac{0.3}{0.3\times0.001+0.995\times0.999}\times0.001$$

So yes you can write that.

Or you could write  $\Pr(\text{neg}\mid \text{inf})\dfrac{\Pr(\text{inf})}{\Pr(\text{neg})} = 0.3\times\dfrac{0.001}{0.3\times0.001+0.995\times0.999}$

If you want it to appear only once, you can also do with $$\Pr(\text{inf}\mid \text{neg})=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{\Pr(\text{neg}\mid \text{not inf})\times\Pr(\text{not inf})}{\Pr(\text{neg}\mid \text{inf})\times\Pr(\text{inf})}}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{0.995\times0.999}{0.3\times0.001}}$$

which shows that $\Pr(\text{inf}\mid \text{neg})$  is an increasing function of $\Pr(\text{neg}\mid \text{inf})$ if the other terms remain constant